# Splash page for drupal 7 website

Tags: 7

i need to put a splash page with flash intro.

I have already a front page with the name `page--front.tpl.php` and how can i put a new splash -page before this home page.

The new splash page will be a simple html page with a flash intro to navigate to the website's home page.

Any suggestion.

....

Comment: will tihs help you? http://drupal.org/project/tinybox

Comment: Nowadays, [jQuery is taking over Flash](http://www.insivia.com/is-jquery-taking-over-flash/). I think tinybox would be useful as Mohammed suggested.

Comment: Sithu-- 
it is a multilingual site (en & arabic).
i changed  mind and decided to put a simple page with a site log and links to the  English and Arabic home pages. not a flash.I hope the tinybox will be helpful.

Comment: @harikris, check my answer for the other option.

Comment: @Mohammed you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend to take advantage of [jQuery over Flash](http://www.whatcreative.co.uk/blog/website-design/why-you-should-mostly-use-jquery-over-flash/). As Mohammed suggested, you could try the [TinyBox](http://drupal.org/project/tinybox) module.

But, the other option is the [Splashify](http://drupal.org/project/splashify) module:

> Display a splash page anywhere on your site by redirecting the user,
>   showing a lightbox, or displaying a popup. This module is designed to
>   be search engine friendly, mobile device friendly and offers multiple
>   configuration options.

Answer (score 4):

[Splash](http://drupal.org/project/splash) module is the rescue! It can do what you need.
Drupal 7 version is [Splashify](http://drupal.org/project/splashify).

Comment: I think it is not for D7.

Comment: no support for D7

Comment: yes nits not for D7!..any other solution?

Comment: Use http://drupal.org/project/tinybox as suggested @Shameem

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: @AyeshK, I have mentioned Splashify in my answer. :)

Comment: I didn't have Splashify mentioned in my initial reply and then went through the Splash module queue to realize tat Splashify is the D7 one. I upvoted :)

Comment: @AyeshK, yes, I noticed your edit and mine were at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it using cookies.

step1. create splash page

step2. write code in php to set and check cookies

step3. if cookies exists then no redirection. If not exists then set cookies and redirect to splash page.

The code can be written on front page tpl.

Comment: With bare bones, this is the way. But embedding code in tpl.php is not the best idea because modules can do better and in this case, there are modules to do that. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Also i found [Front Page](http://drupal.org/project/front) module

> The Front Page module allows for customised home pages dependant on role. The pages can be of the following types:
>
> - **Alias** (only 2.x branch) - Allows for another Drupal path to be shown
>     as the home page without redirecting the user.
> - **Redirect** - Allows you to redirect users to a local or remote URL.
> - **Themed** - Allows you to enter some static text that will be placed
>     into the content area of a standard Drupal page.
> - **Full** - Allows for static content to be displayed to the screen as is.
>     This method does not pass through Drupal's theming system.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use the [Panels module](http://drupal.org/project/panels). Have a look at the [Panopoly distribution](http://drupal.org/project/panopoly).
More about Panels:

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained permissions.